# Dimension of real vector space $S_m$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Consider the matrix $$
M=
  \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 & -1 \\
    0 & 1 & 0  \\
    1 & 1 & -1
  \end{bmatrix}
$$
Let $S_m$ be the set of $3\times3$ matrices $N$ such that $MN=0$.

Then, the dimension of the real vector space $S_m$ is? I know that the answer is $3$. Can anyone explain me why the answer is $3$? I dont know the reason.

Comment: $MN =0$ means that each column of $N$ is in the kernel of $M$. How big is the kernel of $M$? How many free parameters does that give you when you try to build $N$?

Answer (score 0):

hint:

Suppose $v$ is a vector such that $Mv=0$.

Then $\begin{bmatrix} v & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \in S_m.$

Can you construct two other elements of $S_m$ such that they form a basis of $S_m$?

Answer (score 0):

### Given

$$
 \mathbf{A} =
\left[
\begin{array}{ccr}
 1 & 0 & -1 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 1 & 1 & -1 \\
\end{array}
\right]
$$

### Observation

The null space 
$$
 \mathcal{N}\left( \mathbf{A} \right) = \text{span} \left\{ \,
\left[ \begin{array}{c}
  1 \\ 0 \\ 1
\end{array} \right]
\,\right\}
$$

### Conclusion

The matrix 
$$
 \mathbf{N} = 
\left[ \begin{array}{c}
  %
  \alpha
  \left[ \begin{array}{c}
    1 \\ 0 \\ 1
  \end{array} \right] &
  %
  \beta
  \left[ \begin{array}{c}
    1 \\ 0 \\ 1
  \end{array} \right] &
  %
  \gamma
  \left[ \begin{array}{c}
    1 \\ 0 \\ 1
  \end{array} \right]
  %
\end{array} \right]
$$
where the arbitrary complex constants satisfy
$$
 \lvert \alpha \rvert +
 \lvert \beta  \rvert +
 \lvert \gamma \rvert > 0
$$

Answer (score 0):

Let's choose a member $N$ of $S_m$:
$$
N=\begin{bmatrix}
a_1&a_2&a_3\\
b_1&b_2&b_3\\
c_1&c_2&c_3
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Then
\begin{eqnarray}
\begin{bmatrix}
0&0&0\\
0&0&0\\
0&0&0
\end{bmatrix}
&=&
\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&-1\\
0&1&0\\
1&1&-1
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
a_1&a_2&a_3\\
b_1&b_2&b_3\\
c_1&c_2&c_3
\end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}
a_1-c_1&a_2-c_2&a_3-c_3\\
b_1&b_2&b_3\\
a_1+b_1-c_1&a_2+b_2-c_2&a_3+b_3-c_3
\end{bmatrix}.
\end{eqnarray}
It follows that
$$
c_i=a_i, \quad b_i=0\quad \forall i=1,2,3.
$$
Hence
$$
N=\begin{bmatrix}
a_1&a_2&a_3\\
b_1&b_2&b_3\\
c_1&c_2&c_3
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
a_1&a_2&a_3\\
0&0&0\\
a_1&a_2&a_3
\end{bmatrix}
=\sum_{i=1}^3a_iN_i,
$$
with
$$
N_1=\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&0\\
0&0&0\\
1&0&0
\end{bmatrix},\quad 
N_2=\begin{bmatrix}
0&1&0\\
0&0&0\\
0&1&0
\end{bmatrix},\quad
N_3=\begin{bmatrix}
0&0&1\\
0&0&0\\
0&0&1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
It follows that $S_m$ is spanned by $\{N_1,N_2,N_3\}$. If $a_1,a_2,a_3$ are three scalars such that $\sum_{i=1}^3a_iN_i=0$, then
$$
0=\begin{bmatrix}
0&0&0\\
0&0&0\\
0&0&0
\end{bmatrix}
=\sum_{i=1}^3a_iN_i
=\begin{bmatrix}
a_1&a_2&a_3\\
0&0&0\\
a_1&a_2&a_3
\end{bmatrix},
$$
i.e. $a_1=a_2=a_3=0$. This shows that $N_1,N_2,N_3$ are linearly independent. Thus $\{N_1,N_2,N_3\}$ is a basis for $S_m$ and therefore 
$$
\dim S_m=|\{N_1,N_2,N_3\}|=3.
$$